# Received fatal alert: protocol_version - Client Hello sending the Tls version as 1.0

Tags: ibm-midrange, ikvm

We are using IKVM to convert the JT400 (JTOpen) jar to connect AS400 using our C# application to connect securely using the secureAS400 class. from our application, if we capture the packet we come to know that client hello was sending the TLS version as 1.0 and the server is rejecting that connection after that with the following error message Received fatal alert: protocol_version.

please let me know if I need to set any environment variable or any registry entries to make it work ?

With Thanks
Amjath

We haved tried direct java application which is working fine, but when we convert the jar using IKVM to use it in our c# application we are getting this error (Received fatal alert: protocol_version) because the client hello was sending the tls version as 1.0.